# Python multithreaded TCP socket server in python

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, plugins, tcp

I am learning how to create multithreaded socket server in Python. I used example from some site that I don't remember. I am trying to create simple plugin system but I am not successful. It says that I am passing 3 arguments instead of 2. This is my code:

```
def handler(clientsock,addr):
    while 1:
        data = clientsock.recv(BUFF)
        if not data: break
        data_sanitized = data.rstrip()
        print repr(addr) + ' received: ' + repr(data_sanitized)
        from plugins.helloWorld import helloWorld
        clazz.fireIt(clientsock,data)#HERE IS THE PROBLEM I THINK
        if "close" == data.rstrip(): break
    clientsock.close()
    print addr, "CLIENT CLOSED CONNECTION"
if __name__=='__main__':
    ADDR = (HOST, PORT)
    serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serversock.setsockopt(SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    serversock.bind(ADDR)
    print 'STARTED SERVER, WAITING FOR CONNECTIONS', PORT
    serversock.listen(5)
    while 1:
        clientsock, addr = serversock.accept()
        print 'INCOMING CONNECTION FROM: ', addr
        thread.start_new_thread(handler, (clientsock, adde))
```

and this is my plugin:

```
from socket import *
def response(key):
    return '<response>' + key + '</response>'
class helloWorld():
    def fireIt(clientsock,data):
        print clientsock
        clientsock.send(response(data))
        print 'SENDING: ' + repr(response(data))
```

Thank you

Comment: that problem often arises when calling a class method on an instance, because `self` is implicitly passed to the method, so you end up with 3 actual arguments instead of the immediately visible 2

Comment: I am moving from PHP, can you post code example how it can be solved? Thanks